# how to create relation between two spinner

Tags: android, spinner

Let's say my purpose with an example.i have two spinner one of them contain provinces name and the other contain cities of selected province,what is the best way to create relation between this spinners?

Comment: relation means what? you want set spinner  based on first spinner ?

Comment: yes,the value of second spinner should be loaded based on the first spinner

Comment: Just create a setOnItemSelected method for spinner 1. Then write down if statements (if (spinner1.contentsEquals("whatever")) then populate the values for second spinner programatically

Comment: I have a lot of data and with this way i should use too many "if" statement,is there any simpler way?!

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is the only way. Although I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment as for a potential solution; I have found an example of how it can be implemented 
[Populate Second Spinner Based on Selection of First Spinner](http://www.javaknowledge.info/populate-second-spinner-based-on-selection-of-first-spinner)

Let me know if it works or if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
provincesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View  selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // update data set for your cities spinner depend on province selected
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }

});
```

Hope it help !

Comment: how it will create relation. He wants something else

Comment: He want data set of citiesSpinner(second spinner) to be loaded based on the provincesSpinner(first spinner) chosen, as his comment above. So I suggest him change the citiesSpinner data set every times provincesSpinner is selected. The list of cities depend on specific province.